# How to execute a javascript command only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a function the calls an HTTP Request GET to compare a given value to check if it matches any element within the array. If there's no match, I want to put that given value into an array but my problem is that since I'm looping through many elements, I get duplicates inside my array when I just need it to display one. Here is my code:

```
 $scope.fetchParcel = function()
     {

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/infiniti/' + $scope.infinitiId, 
        })
        .success(function(a){

            angular.forEach($scope.parcels, function(parcel, key){
                    angular.forEach(parcel, function(par){


                        if(par == $scope.shipper_ref_no){
                            $scope.scans.push(parcel);
                            $scope.checked++;

                            $scope.parcels.splice(key, 1);

                        }
                        if(par != $scope.shipper_ref_no){
                            $scope.excludeds.push($scope.shipper_ref_no);
                        }


                    });

            });

        });

}
```

In the last part where it says `$scope.excludes.push($scope.shipper_ref_no);` It's correct that it stores the shipper_ref_no into the array but since there is three elements within the array, it actually stores the shipper_ref_no thrice when I just need it to store once after the check finds out that it matches none of the elements. How do I accomplish this?

example of the array:

```
 [
 -{
    id: 1
    t: "1122"
    srn: "23"
  }
 -{
    id: 2
    t: "234"
    srn: "23"
  }
 -{
    id: 3
    t: "dd"
    srn: "44"
  }
 ]
```

If my input is let's say "444kkkddd" obviously there is no match for any of the elements so it puts into my array 444kkkddd  9 times..I just need it to store it once. Don't get me wrong, I know why it's printing it 9 times, but I just need a solution for this to print just once. I've hit a stump.

Comment: can you please setup a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a list of added ids:

```
var addedIds = {};

if(par != $scope.shipper_ref_no){
    if (!addedIds[$scope.shipper_ref_no]) {
        addedIds[$scope.shipper_ref_no] = true;
        $scope.excludeds.push($scope.shipper_ref_no);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I should have thought of this solution a long time ago. I may need to catch some Z's to recharge my brain haha thanks!

Comment: hmm strange. Even if the condition is checking to not push into the array if there is a matching element, it's pushing all data into the array

Comment: what kind of value does $scope.shipper_ref_no contain? A string?

Comment: and can you console.log addedIds to make sure your data is being stored correctly? Also, might be good to throw a toLowerCase() on there to avoid any case mismatches

Comment: `$scope.shipper_ref_no` is a string. I did a console log to addedId's and the data is being stored correctly.

Comment: Make sure you are not reinstantiating addedIds inside of every loop. It should instantiated once somewhere that is accessible to all iterations of the loop

Comment: Ah, I know what's happening. Since I'm splicing the array it's checking for after being a correct match, the element actually DOESN'T exist anymore since it belongs to another array.